# Transformation of a function; different methods, different values?

Tags: functions, inverse, transformation

Given the function $ g(x) = 2f(2x + 2) - 3 $ for the point $ (1, 2) $.

Now, we take 2 common and we get $ f(x) = 2f( 2(x + 1) ) - 3 $; the Horizontal stretch is $ \frac{1}{2} $.

Solving for x:

$2(2 - 1) = 2(1)$

Now, applying the stretch: $ \frac{1}{2} $. For y, the value is pretty simple: $ 1 $.

The answer, however, is $ \frac{-3}{2} $ for x.

What is the wrong step here?

Shouldn't it be independant of the step?

Comment: How should we interpret your first formula? Is this a functional equation that $f$ has to satisfy, or what?

Comment: It's a simple function which has undergone a transformation. Also, I am really sorry, it has to be $g(x)$. I'll edit it real quick.